# how we add delay in between loop of posting facebook friend status through dialog ?

Tags: iphone

i used to dialog for posting friend wall.
here self.fbFriendsInvitedid is array of my friends id.i want delay of dilog open.because if array elements are greter then app crashed..what should i do?

```
 Facebook *fb = [((AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]) fbInstance];
NSLog(@"%@",self.fbFriendsInvited);
NSLog(@"%@",self.fbFriendsInvitedid);
for (int i=0; i<self.fbFriendsInvitedid.count; i++) {
    NSObject *obj=[self.fbFriendsInvitedid objectAtIndex:i];
    NSLog(@"%@",obj);
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   obj,@"to",@"Invite Me", @"name", @"available for iOS apps in Facebook Platform.", @"caption", @"Check out 'Invite Me' for iOS & be my friend here",@"description",@"http://www.inviteme.com",@"link",@"http://www.facebookmobileweb.com/inviteme/img/facebook_icon_large.png", @"picture",nil];

    [fb dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

please help.!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can put your code in some method and call it after the delay like below :

```
[self performSelector:@selector(onClickPost) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: replace 0.5 second with your desired time that you think is enough to avoid crash

Comment: @user2632981 Ohh i see.. but thing you can only decide that where and when you need to call any method how can i help you in this if i'm not aware about your coding and requirement.